# Javascript - Arduino - POST request - WiFi101 - Connection issue

Tags: javascript, post, arduino, http-post, wifi

In my code I am trying to send a POST request to the IFTTT service webhooks (maker).

I'm using a couple of libraries, mainly [WiFi101](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFi101)

I am using an Arduino MKR1000.

I have updated the firmware, and added a certificate for https://maker.ifttt.com:443.

When in the following code I call `sslClient.connect(host, 443);` It fails to make the connection. I have tried bypassing this and just trying to print data to the host, however this also didn't work.

It takes about 10-20 seconds for the function to return as false, if I change the host to an incorrect variable, then it returns as false immediately. I'm assuming this is a good sign since the arduino is trying to connect?

`wifiSetup()` Runs well, connection is established reasonably quickly.

The code I am refering to is below:

Globally defined

```
//WiFi router setup
char ssid[] = "-----";   //network SSID (aka WiFi name)
char pass[] = "-----"; //network password
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
const char* host = "https://maker.ifttt.com";
WiFiSSLClient sslClient;
```

Wifi setup procedure: This runs without problems

```
void wifiSetup() {
  // Check for the presence of the shield
  Serial.print("WiFi101 shield: ");
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    Serial.println("NOT PRESENT");
    return; // don't continue
  }
  Serial.println("DETECTED");
  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to Network named: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);                   // print the network name (SSID);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network:
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);
  }
  printWifiStatus();                        // you're connected now, so print out the status
}
```

The code below is the one causing problems

```
void sendMessage() {
  if (sslClient.connect(host, 443)) {
    //change this to your Maker setting from https://ifttt.com/services/maker/settings
    String  data = "randomdata";
    sslClient.println("POST /trigger/tank_empty/with/key/bxa");
    sslClient.println("Host: https://maker.ifttt.com");
    sslClient.println("Content-Type: application/json");
    sslClient.print("Content-Length: ");
    sslClient.println(data.length());
    sslClient.println();
    sslClient.print(data);
    sslClient.stop();
    Serial.println("IFTTT request Sucessful");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("IFTTT request failed");
  }
  delay(20000000);
}
```

Does anyone have any solutions, or things to troubleshoot?

Thanks for your help all,

Let me know if you need any extra information.

Comment: `https://maker.ifttt.com` is not a valid host.

Comment: Also [don't cross post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). You already asked this [on Arduino SE](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/51268).

Comment: I don't understand? What would constitute it to be a valid host? (Thanks for the heads up on the posting guidelines, I removed the old post)

Comment: would `ifttt.com` or `maker.ifttt.com` be it?

Comment: Possibly you are being blocked by the `ifttt.com` webserver

Comment: Ah, why would that be the case?

Comment: I can connect to ifttt.com but not maker.ifttt.com

Answer (score 0):

`https://maker.ifttt.com` is not a valid host. A valid host is either an IP address or a domain. `https://` is not a part of the domain, but an URL.

You are also missing the HTTP protocol version (`HTTP/1.1`), which could potentially cause problems.

```cpp
const char* host = "maker.ifttt.com";
```

```cpp
sslClient.println("POST /trigger/tank_empty/with/key/bxa HTTP/1.1");
sslClient.print("Host: ");
sslClient.println(host); // non hardcoded host header
sslClient.println("Content-Type: application/json");
sslClient.print("Content-Length: ");
sslClient.println(data.length());
sslClient.println();
sslClient.print(data);
sslClient.stop();
```

Comment: I tried changing the host, but now it fails to connect immediately

Comment: I've managed to get it working with www.google.com, but when I try use maker.ifttt.com it refuses to connect